# CSS & images breaking after mapping application deployed on Tomcat to my domain

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, tomcat, mod-proxy, digital-ocean

I've installed Tomcat 9.0.27 on my Digital Ocean droplet running Ubuntu 18.04.3.
I deployed my Java WAR on Tomcat and am able to access it on the URL: 
`http://example.com:8080/app_name`
I want to be able to directly access my WAR serving JSP through my domain. 
So, when I hit `example.com` it directly serves my Java application.

I have tried several links to do the same. According to one of them (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-tie-domain-name-with-application-running-on-tomcat), I did the following steps:
1. Enabled "proxy" and "proxy_http" using `a2enmod`
2. Restarted Apache2 service using `systemctl restart`
3. Created a new virtual host in a file named /etc/apache2/sites-available/tomcat.conf with the following contents:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com

    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/app_name/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/app_name/
</VirtualHost>
```

4. Enabled 'tomcat' site using a2ensite
5. Restarted Apache2 service using `systemctl restart`

Now when I hit `example.com` it does serve my homepage but all the CSS styles and images seem to be broken. The hyperlinks also don't work anymore. 
My application is still being served at `example.com:8080/app_name` and on this URL everything works perfectly.

Please help me out with this.

Comment: what does your browser network tab say?

Comment: @mightyteja how do I check that?

Comment: Here you go - https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network

Answer (score 0):

Deployed my WAR as ROOT.war in the /opt/tomcat/webapps/ directory.

No other answers/suggestions worked.